# need an example for Entity Framework when registering saga repositories with autofac

Tags: autofac, masstransit, automatonymous

The masstransit documentation has an example for NHiberbate, does anyone have the same example, but using entity framework (SagaDbContextFactory,SagaDbContext) instead of NHibernate

```
// do not forget registering saga repositories (example for NHibernate)
var mappings = mappingsAssembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
        (t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(SagaClassMapping<>) ||
        t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ClassMapping<>)))
    .ToArray();
builder.Register(c => new SqlServerSessionFactoryProvider(connString, mappings).GetSessionFactory())
    .As<ISessionFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NHibernateSagaRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(ISagaRepository<>));
```

Comment: Just open an issue on GitHub and I will fix it.

Comment: Added: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/790

Comment: This is not really a documentation issue. One instance/mapping/repo registration is straightforward but it's not really the same level of generalisation as NH one.

Answer (score 2):

I've registered mine like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SomeType).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf(); 

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SagaRepository<,>)).As(typeof(ISagaRepository<,>));

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SagaDbContext<,>));
```

And then implemented the SagaRepository interface:

```
internal class SagaRepository<TSaga, TSagaClassMapping> : EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<TSaga>, ISagaRepository<TSaga, TSagaClassMapping>
    where TSaga : class, ISaga where TSagaClassMapping : SagaClassMapping<TSaga>, new()
{
    public SagaRepository(
        IWorkerConfiguration workerConfiguration)
        : base(() => new SagaDbContext<TSaga, TSagaClassMapping>(workerConfiguration.ConnectionStrings["SagaRepository"]))
    {
    }
}
```

For the mappings I use a base class:

```
internal abstract class BaseInstanceStateMap<TInstance> : SagaClassMapping<TInstance>, IInstanceStateMap<TInstance> where TInstance : BaseSagaInstance
{
    protected BaseInstanceStateMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.CorrelationId);
        this.Property(x => x.CurrentState).HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(x => x.Initiated).HasColumnType("datetime2").IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Created).HasColumnType("datetime2").IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.StateChanged).HasColumnType("datetime2").IsOptional();
    }
}
```

Which I then inherit for each of my mappings:

```
internal class ProductIndexingStateMap : BaseInstanceStateMap<ProductIndexingSagaInstance>
{
    public ProductIndexingStateMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.ProductId);
        this.Property(x => x.ProductCorrelation);
        this.Property(x => x.EncryptedConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can register `EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<T>` as generic but it will require you to register *one* `DbContext`. If you use `SagaDbContext` - you cannot have more than one saga in your application. The only way to go there is to bind custom repository implementation and `SagaDbContext` via generic type parameters, this is what @slinzerthegod is doing in his example.

You can also create your own context that will register all types. For example:

```
public class AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext : DbContext
{
    readonly Assembly _mappingAssembly;

    public AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    public AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, ObjectContext objectContext, bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
        : base(objectContext, dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    public AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    public AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, string nameOrConnectionString, DbCompiledModel model)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString, model)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    public AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, DbConnection existingConnection, DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    protected AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    protected AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(Assembly mappingAssembly, DbCompiledModel model)
        : base(model)
    {
        _mappingAssembly = mappingAssembly;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) =>
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(_mappingAssembly);
}
```

If you have such class, you can do the following:

```
builder.Register(c => new AssemblyScanningSagaDbContext(typeof(MySagaMapping).Assembly,
    connectionString).As<DbContext>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityFrameworkSagaRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(ISagaRepository<>))
    .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterStateMachineSagas(typeof(MySaga).Assembly);
```

Autofac is able to compose a factory delegate automatically and will inject it to the repository constructor.

[Here is the scanning context as gist](https://gist.github.com/alexeyzimarev/34542645ff8f27550d0679c7cb696111).